# easy Jquery about selecting children and browsing DOM

Tags: jquery, html, dom

Well I think it should be easy to do it. However I just cant wrap my head around it.. this is the code i have.. In my app i am having the .scroller class selected. From there i used the .parent() to get to #exerciseWrapper class. My goal is the h2 tag. I dont know how to go on from here nothing works. find() browses whole DOM and children() only browses one child..

$('.scroller').parent() something something ?? hmm..

```
          var append='<div class="exerciseWrapper"><div class="allTextWrapper"><div class="headerWrapper"><h2 class="exerciseHeaderName">'+exerciseName+'</h2></div><div class="lastConfigUsedHeader">Last configuration used:</div><div class="lastUsedConfig">Sets: 10, Kg: 12302, Time:10.30</div></div><div class="scroller">'+ 
'<div class="divImgContainer"><img src="../images/exercises/logo.png" class="scrollImages"></div>'+
'<div class="divImgContainer"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png" class="scrollImages"></div>'+
'<div class="divImgContainer"><img src="../images/exercises/logo.png" class="scrollImages"></div>'+
'<div class="divImgContainer"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png" class="scrollImages"></div>'+
'<div class="divImgContainer"><img src="../images/exercises/logo.png" class="scrollImages"></div>'+
'<div class="divImgContainer"><img src="../images/exercises/MuscleGroup1.png" class="scrollImages"></div>'+
      '</div></div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find doesn't browse the whole DOM you would be able to select:

```
$('.scroller').parent('div.exerciseWrapper').find('div.headerWrapper h2')
```

Comment: i need to get the content of of h2.. your code is finde but i get the content of all h2 objects all in one string.. THere are multiple scroller classer with .scroller in it.. how get i get only se selected scroller classes elements?

Comment: and i im a suck a noob.. ofcause with 'THIS' :D doh.. thought i already had that done.. THX GUYS!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `find()` enumerates only the elements under the active element(s). From jQuery API:

> **Description**: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

You should be able to use:

```
$('.scroller').parent().find('h2')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.scroller').parent('div.exerciseWrapper').find('div.headerWrapper h2')
```

worked for me